# Add record in detail in master-detail ADF in two sessions

Tags: java, jpa, ejb, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

if I have a master entity :

```
@Entity
public class Test implements Serializable {
    
   
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="TEST_ID" nullable = false)
    private BigDecimal testId;
    @Column(unique = true, length = 30)
    private String code;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String name;
    @Column(name="SYS_VERSION_NUMBER",nullable = false, length = 50)
    private Long sysVersionNumber;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "test", orphanRemoval=true, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    private List<TestDetail> testDetailList;
    
    public Test() {}
    
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

   

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public BigDecimal getTestId() {
        return testId;
    }

    public void setTestId(BigDecimal testId) {
        this.testId = testId;
    }

    public Long getSysVersionNumber() {
        return sysVersionNumber;
    }

    public void setSysVersionNumber(Long sysVersionNumber) {
        this.sysVersionNumber = sysVersionNumber;
    }

    
    public List<TestDetail> getTestDetailList() {
        return testDetailList;
    }
    
    
    public void setTestDetailList(List<TestDetail> testDetailList) {
        this.testDetailList = testDetailList;
    }

    public TestDetail addTestDetailList(TestDetail testDetail) {
        getTestDetailList().add(testDetail testDetail);
        testDetail.setTest(this);
        testDetail.setTestId(this.getTestId());
        return testDetail;
    }

    public TestDetail removeProvbilling(TestDetail testDetail) {
        getTestDetailList().remove(testDetail testDetail);
        testDetail.setTest(null);
        testDetail.setTestId(null);
        return testDetail;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (this == object) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(object instanceof Test)) {
            return false;
        }
        final Test other = (Test) object;
        if (!(id == null ? other.testId == null : testId.equals(other.testId))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int PRIME = 37;
        int result = 1;
        result = PRIME * result + ((test == null) ? 0 : test.hashCode());
        return result;
    }    
}
```

and I have a detail entity

```
@Entity
public class Testdetail implements Serializable {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "TESTDETAIL_ID", nullable = false)
    private BigDecimal testdetailId;
    
    
    @Version
    @Column(name = "SYS_VERSION_NUMBER")
    private Long sysVersionNumber;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "TEST_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private TEST test;
    @Column(name = "TEST_ID",)
    private BigDecimal testId;
    @Column 
    private String name;
    
    public Testdetail() {
        
    }

    public Test getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(Test test) {
        this.test = test;
    }
    

    public void setTestId(BigDecimal testId) {
        this.testId = testId;
    }

    public BigDecimal getTestId() {
        return testId;
    }
    
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
 public Long getSysVersionNumber() {
        return sysVersionNumber;
    }

    public void setSysVersionNumber(Long sysVersionNumber) {
        this.sysVersionNumber = sysVersionNumber;
    }

}
```

if I run the page in twice two tabs with the same Test record and add new record for 'testDetail' in the first tab then add record for 'testDetail' in second tab (I am calling method **mergeTest()** in sessionbean which invoke **em.merge(test)** on saving), the added record in fist tab is gone even though sysversionnumber is working properly to prevent user from editing existing records if they were edited in the second tab.

is there a way to prevent user from adding record in second tab or to lock master record if it is used through EntityManager in sessionBean?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution after calling `em.merge(test);` I have to lock it using
`em.lock(test, LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT);`